# why constructor called only one times?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have some code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() { cout << "called" << endl; }
};


A* foo()
{
    static A* a = new A();
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    A *p = foo();
    cout << std::addressof(*p) << endl;

    A *pp = foo();
    cout << std::addressof(*pp) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I called foo() twice.

but class A constructor called once.

I know that "static" keywords only use the same address space.

have a "static" keyword another spec that I don't know?

this code is working(constructor called twice) if remove static.

Comment: The `static` has nothing whatsoever to do with address spaces. Don't trust whoever told you that.

Answer (score 5):

A function static is initialized only once. That's precisely what `static` does.

Comment: Yes, when you use static, it means that you cannot manipulate the function.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is called whenever the object of a class is created. Since you've used static keyword then the object created only once on first call only now if you call again it will not again declare that object. So that's why you are getting only on constructor call.